# Initiating a binary search tree using a rootNode that is null

Tags: java

I have this node class

```
public class Node {
  Node right;
  Node left;
  int value;
  Node(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  Node insertValue(int v){
     if(this == null){
         return new Node(v);
     }
     //Rest of the method
  }
}
```

I want to make a rootNode that is the tree. If it is null, the tree is empty. **Edit: The methods to populate the tree, find minimum, etc. must be recursive methods of class Node**

```
class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Node rootNode = null;
    rootNode.insertValue(5);
  }

}
```

Of course, since `rootNode == null`, I can't use it to call `insertValue`.

I am looking for a way to populate an empty tree(rootNode == null) with inner methods. Any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: what does insertValue do?   this==null is always false

Comment: `if (this == null)` is meaningless, `this` can *never* be `null` by definition.

Comment: @Sam insertValue is meant to populate the tree recursively. For instance, if the value is less than the rootNode, rootNode.left should equal new Node(value)

Comment: @azurefrog I didn't think of that :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new class `Tree` which contains (only) the root node and methods to work with like `insertValue()`. The `Node` class will become more or less a private helper class for the internals of the tree.

```
public class Tree {
    private Node root;

    public void insertValue(int v) {}
    public int getSize() {}
    public int getValue(int index) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I want to solve this by implementing all functions as recursive methods in the Node class.

Comment: @tore You still can do that.

Comment: Hello again! I can't for the life of me figure this out. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the task:
_Assume now that you don’t have a Tree class, i.e. only the structure (The Node class I showed). An empty tree is refered to as a null pointer; the root is used to refer to the tree. Implement all of the above functions  as recursive methods in the Node class._ According to this task, I thought I was not allowed to solve it using any extra classes.

Comment: @tore Then you don't use the `Tree` class but instead use a simple variable of type `Node`. When it is `null` it is considered empty. When you want to "add" a your first value you write `new Node(...);`, after that you use the `insertValue()` method.

Comment: I think I now see what messed me up. I thought everything had to be handled by the node it self. The empty tree had to check if it was null and act accordingly. If I can use a method in my main class to check if it is null and then set rootNode to the first value, then I know how to do it. Thank you for clearing this up for me :)